# Comparing arrays within functions

Tags: ruby

The two identical functions being called here output a string of numbers that vary in length each time. My question is how could I compare the length of them both and then do something with it?

For example:
if random_method(2) length < random_method(3) length --> do this

```
def random_method()

  rand1 = rand(2)
  if rand1 == 1
    rand2 = rand(1..25)

  else
    rand2 = 0
  end
  rand2
end

def random_method2()
  x_vals = [99]
  x_vals << x_vals.last - random_method while x_vals.last > 0
  puts ": #{x_vals.join(", ")}"
end

def random_method3()
  x_vals = [99]
  x_vals << x_vals.last - random_method while x_vals.last > 0
  puts ": #{x_vals.join(", ")}"
end

random_method2()
random_method3()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment you only store the arrays in local variables within the methods but do not return the generated array (you only print a string representation of the arrays). To compare and to do something with the arrays you need to return the arrays and store them in variables.

Something like this might works:

```
def random_number
  if rand(2) == 1
    rand(1..25)
  else
    0
  end
end

def random_array
  array = [99]
  array << (array.last - random_number) while array.last > 0
  puts array.inspect
  array
end

array_1 = random_array
array_2 = random_array

if array_1.length < array_2.length
  puts "Array 1 is shorter"
else
  puts "Array 1 is longer or equal in size to Array 2"
end
```

Note that I refactored your methods a bit to remove the duplication and to follow common Ruby idioms.